# Can the "and" word be replaced by the ampersand, "&", in citations with IEEE style?

Tags: citations, citation-style, ieee

Can the "and" word be replaced by the ampersand "&" in citations with IEEE style?

I have searched for an answer to this question online but I did not find anything so far.

Comment: Do you mean if the word "and" appears in the title, or as a separation between authors?

Comment: I guess the name of the article cannot be changed in the citation because that gets typed within double quotation marks. Therefore my question has to do with any part of the citation different from the name of the article.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: Where else besides title and author listing could this be?  (1) The journal name?  I do often see journal names abbreviated. (2) The volume number?  As in vol. 3&4.  (3) The page numbering?  As in 34-67 & 102-130.

Comment: Thanks @GEdgar, that is exactly what I meant when I said "any part of the citation different from the name of the article".

Comment: Do you want to save a few lines, or why would it matter how you format the references?

Answer (score 4):

IEEE is based on the Chicago Manual of Style.

It seems that the Chicago Style prefers to use the word *and* rather than ampersands (&) in journal titles. [See here](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Abbreviations/faq0034.html) for a remark regarding journal titles:

> Since there is no easy way to check whether an author’s choices are random or scrupulous, conventionally editors have chosen one style or the other to impose throughout. Chicago prefers *and*. Even now that it’s possible to check online, we think it’s more expedient to choose one style and be consistent, given the amount of research it would entail to check the style of and in every title

Under the heading "Permissible changes to quoted title" (chapter 8.174), the manual even allows users to replace a given ampersand (&) to an *and* (rather than vice versa):

> When a title is quoted, its original spelling [...], hyphenation, and punctuation should be preserved. [...] As a matter of editorial discretion, an ampersand (&) may be changed to *and*, or, more rarely, a numeral may be spelled out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer!